# Why is my simple self-referential association getting inverse_of wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model like this:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing
  has_many :things
end
```

In rails 5 this was working. In rails 6.1, this happens:

```rb
t1 = Thing.create
t2 = Thing.create(thing: t1)
t3 = Thing.create(thing: t2)

t3.thing.id # t2 id, correct
Thing.find(t3.thing_id).thing.id # t1 id, correct
t3.thing.thing.id # t3 id, incorrect! for some reason it loops back when loading this record
```

the behavior is fixed by adding inverse_of:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :thing, inverse_of: :things
  has_many :things, inverse_of: :thing
end
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: This doesn't work in rails 5 either. The `<<` operator dosen't work in a class definition And `Things` is not a class.

Comment: Hi @asceta - I'm not sure what you mean by the << operator

Comment: He's referring to the `<<` typo you have in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an existing rails bug:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43478
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41552